# How to search for an occurence of a string present in one dataframe in a different data frame and incrementing a count in a third data frame

Tags: r

I have three data frames. First data frame is as follows

```
 ID      Col1    Col2    Col3
 XX:11   1       0       0
 YY:22   1       0       0
 ZZ:33   0       1       0
 AA:44   0       0       1
 BB:55   0       0       1
```

Second data frame is as follows

```
 ID      Col1
 YY:22   0
 AA:44   1
 XX:11   1
 DD:99   0
```

Third data frame is

```
 ColA    ColB    ColC
```

ColA,ColB and ColC correspond to Col1,Col2 and Col3 respectively from data frame 1.

I am trying to find ID`s from second data frame which exist in the first and if they exist, then increment the corresponding Col* in the third data frame.

For example
taking ID YY:22 from the second data frame. This exists in the first data frame , then look to see which column(from Col1, Col2 and Col3) has a 1 and then accordingly increment the corresponding column in third data frame. IN this case YY:22 has a 1 in COl1 in the first data frame, so ColA needs to be incremented in the third data frame.

edit:
expected output is

```
 ColA    ColB    ColC
    2       0       1
```

Col1 in Data Frame 2 is irrelevant

Comment: So the 2nd dataframe `Col1` column is irrelevant? Maybe read about `%in%`, `merge`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr` we can do:

```
df3 = df1 %>%
    filter(ID %in% df2$ID) %>%
    summarize_at(vars(Col1:Col3), sum)
```

Output:

```
  Col1 Col2 Col3
1    2    0    1
```

If you need the column names to be A, B, C then you can just rename them now like akrun's answer:

```
names(df3) <- paste0("Col", LETTERS[1:3])
```

Answer (score 2):

You could give `semi_join` from `dplyr` a try:

```
library(dplyr)
df3 <- df1 %>% 
  semi_join(df2, by ="ID") %>%
  summarise_at(vars(Col1:Col3), funs(sum))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `match` between the 'ID's of the two dataset, subset the 'df1' based on that and get the `sum` of the 'Col' columns with `colSums`

```
df3 <- as.data.frame.list(colSums(df1[match(df2$ID, df1$ID, nomatch = 0),-1]))
names(df3) <- paste0("Col", LETTERS[1:3])
```